# Show slider value as a tip on mouse over

Tags: extjs, extjs4, slider

How can I show the value of an ExtJs4 slider as a tool tip on mouse over. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Wow 9 years and 7 months later...

You were looking for reversePixelValue

```
slider.el.on('mousemove', function (event,element) {
            var xy = event.getXY();
                trackPoint = slider.getTrackpoint(event.getXY()),
                value = Ext.util.Format.round(slider.reversePixelValue(trackPoint), me.decimalPrecision),
                pd = Ext.Date.parse(value, 'U'),
                fd = Ext.Date.format(new Date(pd), me.dateFormat);

            tip.setTitle(fd);
            tip.showAt([xy[0]-38, slider.getXY()[1]-31]);
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you checked sample slider in extjs. if not here is the link http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/slider/slider.html. check the `tip-slider` or `custom-tip-slider`.

otherwise you have to work on render event in listner. mouse has `onNodeEnter` event.

```
 listeners: {

    render: function (v) {

            //      On entry into a target node, highlight that node.
            onNodeEnter: function (target, dd, e, data) {
                //You will get the target here, try t 
                Ext.fly(target).addCls('control-target-hover');
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you find some solution here?